# Invalid Bson Object Type for CSV Error on MongoExport

Tags: mongodb

**Scope:**

I have a collection on MongoDB that I want to export to a .csv file. I have done this already, with a similar database, using the MongoExport.exe, executing it right on the server (windows machine, hosting the MongoDB database).

**Problem:**

Once I run the following script

```
mongoexport.exe --fieldFile fields.txt --db AppleStore --collection AppleStoreApps --out applestore.csv --csv --port 21766
```

I start getting the following error messages

```
Invalid BSON object type for CSV output:10
```

It works for some cases, but seems like the majority of records gets this error.

**More Information:**

This is an example of JSON object on mongoDB, that should be exported:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("545c05ea74671a1d1c572da9"),
"url" : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dc-eventos/id782560424?mt=8",
"name" : "DC Eventos",
"developerName" : "FERNANDO COSTA",
"developerUrl" : "https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/fernando-costa/id729986271",
"price" : 0,
"isFree" : true,
"thumbnailUrl" : "http://a4.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple6/v4/ee/a2/5e/eea25e3f-8f12-9dce-c86f-37e5e3d9a8dc/icon350x350.jpeg",
"compatibility" : "Requires iOS 5.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch. This app is optimized for iPhone 5.",
"category" : "Business",
"updateDate" : ISODate("2014-03-22T03:00:00.000Z"),
"version" : "1.82.82.542",
"size" : "16.3 MB",
"languages" : [ 
    "English"
],
"minimumAge" : 4,
"ageRatingReasons" : [],
"rating" : {
    "starsRatingCurrentVersion" : 0,
    "starsVersionAllVersions" : 0,
    "ratingsCurrentVersion" : 0,
    "ratingsAllVersions" : 0
},
"topInAppPurchases" : null
```

}

Answer (score 1):

mongoexport is likely choking on empty array -- `"ageRatingReasons" : []` -- and `null` objects. examine the records one by one and check for a pattern.

csv cannot 'do' arrays and objects hence the need for json and xml. try exporting json and then convert with a variety of json to csv converters that will handle complex or custom flattening of objects such as `[]` to `0` or skipped commas `val,,val` whatever is needed. the jsontocsv convertor must also permit turning off validating, simply because ObjectId("545c05ea74671a1d1c572da9") is invalid json.